# How can I export Playwright + Javascript Test Execution report to Zephyr Scale?

Tags: javascript, playwright, jira-zephyr

We have a Test Automation Framework written in JavaScript with Playwright.
How can I export Playwright + JavaScript Test Execution report to Zephyr Scale?

I am able to generate JUNIT Test report from Playwright. But I am not getting any solution how I can import that result automatically in Zephyr Scale

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own [Custom reporter](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters#custom-reporters), which will send your results through API.

For example, this is how Tesults wrote their reporter - https://github.com/tesults/playwright-tesults-reporter/blob/master/playwright-tesults-reporter.js and this one by Testtomat https://github.com/testomatio/reporter/blob/master/lib/adapter/playwright.js